# What is the process to reassign a variable to point to another in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

At the moment I have the following inside a `for` loop:

```
NewArray.Add(RawDataArray[i].Value);
```

During the course of processing RawDataArray a number of additional arrays will be created, for example NewArray1,NewArray2 etc

At one point I will need NewArray to point to NewArray1 so that the `.Add` method adds the data to NewArray1 and at another point, I need to point NewArray to another NewArray*X*

How do I do this in C#?

### Edit

In order to try and clarify here is a relevant section:

```
    List<object> NewArray = new List<object>();

            for (int i = 1; i <= RawDataArray.Count; i++)
            {
                if (RawDataArray[i].TypeCode == 5005)
                {
                    NewArray.Add(RawDataArray[i].Value);
                }

                if (RawDataArray[i].TypeCode == 5016)
                {
                    //RawDataArray[i] should be added to NewArray1
                    >> Create NewArray1 and "change" NewArray so that it points to NewArray1 <<
                    NewArray.Add(RawDataArray[i].Value);
                }

                if (RawDataArray[i].TypeCode == 5017)
                {
                    //RawDataArray[i] should be added to NewArray2
                    >> Create NewArray2 and "change" NewArray so that it points to NewArray2 <<
                    NewArray.Add(RawDataArray[i].Value);
                }
            }
```

### Additional edit

I guess a little more information is required so you can see the full picture. I have a raw data stream, in this case simulated by RawDataArray (OK terminology of 'array' not correct, accepted!!).

```
    struct TypedValue
        {
            private readonly int typeCode;
            private readonly object value;

            public TypedValue(int typeCode, object value)
            {
                this.typeCode = typeCode;
                this.value = value;
            }

            public int TypeCode { get { return typeCode; } }
            public object Value { get { return value; } }

        }

        static readonly IList<TypedValue> RawDataArray = new ReadOnlyCollection<TypedValue>
        (new[] {
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 1"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 2"),
            new TypedValue(5016,@"-1"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 3"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 4"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 5"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 6"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 7"),
            new TypedValue(5017,@"-1"),
            new TypedValue(5016,@"-1"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 8"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 9"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 10"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 11"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 12"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 13"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 14"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 15"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 16"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 17"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 18"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 19"),
            new TypedValue(5017,@"-1"),
            new TypedValue(5016,@"-1"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 20"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 21"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 22"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 23"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 24"),
            new TypedValue(5017,@"-1"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 25"),
            new TypedValue(5016,@"-1"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 26"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 27"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 28"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 29"),
            new TypedValue(5005,@"String Value 30"),
            new TypedValue(5017,@"-1"),
        });
```

The confusing part is that `typeCode` of 5016 and 5017 form the start and end respectively of a block of data.  That is to say the data between these `typeCodes` needs to go in to a temporary array (or something) which is then inserted in to NewArray.

So, in pseudo code, I have this working thought:

1) `for (int i = 1; i <= RawDataArray.Count; i++)`

2) `if i.typeCode = 5005` then add `i.value` to `NewArray`

3) `if i.typeCode = 5016` then create a temporary array and make NewArray point to it so that calls to the Add method now adds to the temporary array.

4) `if i.typeCode = 5017` then add temporary array to NewArray and the point NewArray variable to NewArray.

```
        List<object> NewArray = new List<object>();

            for (int i = 1; i <= RawDataArray.Count; i++)
            {
                if (RawDataArray[i].TypeCode == 5005)
                {
                    NewArray.Add(RawDataArray[i].Value);
                }

                if (RawDataArray[i].TypeCode == 5016)
                {
                    //RawDataArray[i] should be added to temporary array
                    //Create temporary array and "change" NewArray so that it points to temporary array
                    NewArray.Add(RawDataArray[i].Value);
                }

                if (RawDataArray[i].TypeCode == 5017)
                {
                    //temporary array should be added to NewArray
                    //Add temporary array to NewArray and re-assign NewArray Variable to reference NewArray so that calls to .Add method add to NewArray
                }
            }
```

The idea is this.  As the RawDataArray is iterated through, if it encounters a `typeCode` of 5005 it adds the value to NewArray.  If the `typeCode` is 5016 it starts a temporary array and re-assigns the NewArray variable to point to the temporary array. When it next encounters a 5005 `typeCode` the NewArray variable is pointing to the temporary array so that the add method adds the value to the temporary array.

When the 5017 `typeCode` is found we know that the temporary array is complete and needs to be added to NewArray and so the process completes. Since the NewArray Variable now points to NewArray and not the temporary array, any subsequent .Add calls will add to NewArray (so `typeCode` of 5005 outside the 5016 and 5017 data block is added to NewArray.

This image may also help: http://i.xomf.com/myhln.png

I find an image is perhaps sometimes better.

Comment: Ummmm `NewArray = NewArray1;`?

Comment: So, basically, you want to use `NewArray` like a pointer?

Comment: I guess this "array" whose `Add()` method you're calling is really a `List<T>`, right? If it's `ArrayList`, that's been obsolete for many years, and you should really be using `List<T>` instead.

Comment: Are all your arrays of the same type? Here is good entry point: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton Yes.  That's it exactly.  Use `NewArray` as a pointer.  I wondered if pointer was the correct terminology.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, Yes you are right it is a `List<T>` - I shall update original question :)

Comment: @cosmarchy, no, pointer is not the correct terminology with respect to .NET. 'Normal' variables either hold values, or they hold object references. The latter is what you referred to as a pointer. There are also types that represent pointers, but they are considered "unsafe" and are mostly used to interface with native code (through P/Invoke) ;-)

Comment: @cosmarchy It's not altogether dissimilar to a pointer, and there's a pointer lurking somewhere under the surface -- but in C# we call it a reference. [There are actual pointers in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/pointer-types), though they're very infrequently used, and they're a different thing.

Comment: @cosmarchy Thanks for the update. You can't go calling lists arrays, or you get hordes of mindless language zombies coming at you muttering about generics and willfully ignoring your actual question.

Comment: Brains... brains...

Comment: @EdPlunkett Not to mention it just confuses everyone when you're calling a `.Add()` method on something that you refer to as an array when arrays don't have a `.Add()` method. I think it's less a matter of being pedantic and more a matter of just trying to understand the situation better. Clearer questions = clearer understanding = better answers

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the array, like so:

```
NewArray = List<YourType>(NewArray1);
```

Not sure if that helps, seems like you come from a C++ background and I don't think there's really any way to use it as a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are very powerfull programming tools, but also quite dangerous ones. So by default no Runtime lets you handle naked pointers.

One of the replacement concepts for pointers (and the one you will need here) are references. You have a instance of a class (Array is a class) in memory. Assigned to one or more references. So something like this:

```
//Create a List of List<int>'s
List<List<int>> ListOfLists = new List<List<int>>();

for (int i=0; i < 10){
    List<int> currentList = new List<int>();
    ListOfLists.Add(currentList);
    //Do some work with current list, like filling it with content in a loop.
}

//Do the processing or output of ListOfLists
```

Comment: By default code is not unsafe. So by default you can not use naked pointers ;) I wanted to not point to how he can do it anyway, because doing that just misses half the point and advantage of using C# rather then native C++.

Answer (score 0):

After your clarification on your question I elected to re-answer (as editing is for clarification of existing answers, not for a completely different answer)

This is what you need to do:

```
var results = new List<List<TypedValue>>();
var tempList = new List<TypedValue>();
foreach (var value in RawDataArray)
{
    if (value.TypeCode == 5016) 
        tempList = new List<TypedValue>();

    tempList.Add(value);

    if (value.TypeCode == 5017) 
        results.Add(tempList);
}
```